# HTML5 style scoped attribute gone in Chrome 36+?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, shadow-dom

`<style scoped>` was available in Chrome with experimental platform features enabled, until Chrome 36.
(http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/document-metadata.html#attr-style-scoped)

It is gone with Chrome 37 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped)

I believe to have read something a while ago, but could not find anything anymore. Have they removed it in favour of Shadow DOM?

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/tofu/xct0jo5u/ (working in FireFox, but not in Chrome with experimental web platform features enabled)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, scoped stylesheets have been removed as of Chrome 35 according to the Chromium Dashboard:

http://www.chromestatus.com/features/5374137958662144

> It was partially implemented behind a flag, but was later retracted
>   due to high code complexity.
>   http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/blink-dev/scoped/blink-dev/R1x18ZLS5qQ/Bjuh_cENhlQJ

Comment: It isn't too complex for Firefox's developers; they have the feature released and it works great.